# Using directories for py2app resources

Tags: python, py2app

I have some data files that are directory-sensitive. How do I add them to my .app bundle?

None of the documentation given by py2app says how to specifically do this. However, after looking around the Internet, I found that one can use tuples to add resources in a specific directory structure. I'm assuming the order is `(directoryInResourceFolder, pathToFile)`.

When I tried that, I get the following error:

```
error: No such file or directory: m
```

I don't know why it would be saying that, because none of my tuples are just `m`. Here is the list of tuples that I generated:

```
[('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_BordersSlashes.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_codes.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Dollars.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Fences.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Final.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Fractions.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_FunctionsLimits.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Integrals.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Numbers.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_PowersPrimes.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_SoftFractions.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_test.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Trig.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Unicodes.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/_Vocab.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/Calculus.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/General.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/Geometry and Trigonometry.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/Linear Algebra.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/Logic.txt'), ('src/math_patterns', 'math_patterns/Statistics.txt')]
```

Here is the setup.py I'm using:

```
from setuptools import setup
import os

APP = ['main.py']

# Prepare all of the resources that I would need
RESOURCES = []

p = 'math_patterns'
files = []
for f in os.listdir(p):
    fullPath = os.path.join(p, f)
    if os.path.isfile(fullPath):
        files.append(('src/math_patterns', fullPath))
RESOURCES.extend(files)

PACKAGES = ['lxml']

INCLUDES = ['sip']

OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'packages': PACKAGES,
           'includes': INCLUDES,
           'resources': RESOURCES}

setup(
    app=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app', 'lxml', 'PIL'],
)
```

Thanks for your time in looking at this!

--
EDIT

Using absolute paths made that particular error go away. But now it's trying to create an `.apdisk` in the `math_patterns` directory, which spits out the following error:

```
error:/.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, after realizing that a .app is just a directory, I ended up using a bash script to insert the files in the right places for me. Who needs py2app for that?

It's kind of silly, really.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python setup.py py2app
```

not

```
$ python setup.py py2app -A
```